# NgRx- How should I fire a service call only when a previous service call response is returned

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am using ngrx5, sample effect code  shown in below.

We have a updating customer infom user case. Users trigger a number of actions (SaveCustomersAction), corresponding Rest service calls fired once actions are emitted.

For example, three service calls (this.customerService.updateCustomer) are fired to update customer information. They almost fired in the same time. it does not work for my app.

Because, we use edition number for concurrency checks. The updated edition number will be returned from the first service call and second service call needs that edition number in order to update customer info.

It means that I have to wait the first service call response and then make the second service call. After that, wait for the second service call response and then fire the third one.

My question is that how should I fire a service call only when the previous service call response is returned in Ngrx effects?  or how to chain actions together, i.e. dispatch second action only the first action is resolved?

Any suggestions?

Thank you

```
@Effect()
      updateCustomerInfo$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(CustomerActionTypes.SaveCustomersAction),
        switchMap((action: customerActions.SaveCustomersAction) => {
          return this.customerService.updateCustomer(action.payload).pipe(
            map(result => {
              return new customerActions.SaveCustomersSuccessAction({
                Edition: {customerId: result.Id, edition: result.edition},
                Customers: action.payload.Customers
              });
            }),
            catchError ( (error) => {
             . . .
            })
        );
        }))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have an effect for each of your service response `success` and `error` that way you can easily have multiple things depend on the result of any one of your service response.

So make more actions each represent the start and end of an API call.

```
  @Effect()
  SaveCustomer$ = this.actions$.ofType(SaveCustomersAction).pipe(
    concatMap(() => {
      return this.customerService.updateCustomer(action.payload)
        .pipe(
          map(pizzas => new SaveCustomersSuccessAction({})),
          catchError(error => of(new SomeError(error)))
        );
    })
  );

  @Effect()
  AfterUpdateCustomer$ = this.actions$.ofType(SaveCustomersSuccessAction).pipe(
    map((action: myOtherInterface) => action.payload),
    concatMap(payload => {
      return this.myService
        .doSomething(payload)
        .pipe(
          map(data => new MyAwesomeness(data)),
          catchError(error => of(new myAwesomeError(error)))
        );
    })
  );
```

Doing it this way makes it very easy to read and follow along and when there is errors the function is small enough to realize where you might have a problem.

Comment: HI thank you for the answers, what is the different between the two effects ?thanks

Comment: The difference is the action that each effect is waiting for. One is `SaveCustomersAction` and the other is `SaveCustomersSuccessAction`